# Python: getting the list of all articles belonging to a certain category from Wikipedia

Tags: python, list, wikipedia

I have a category on Wikipedia (for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Member_states_of_the_United_Nations ) and the task is to get the list of all articles that belong to this category and print the following result of the terminal (in Python), like this:

A: 11

B: 17

...

Y: 1

Z: 2

I have just one idea (but I'm not sure is it right) - I am using import wikipedia. Are there any other ways to solve this task except using import wikipedia?

Comment: selenium?...................

Comment: @AhmetBilgin idk how to use Selenium in Python but I used it in Java. So I'd like to solve this task in two ways (in Python, of course) - with import wikipedia and in Selenium

Comment: I do not know how to establish a connection between the two languages, but maybe if it is a script, you can stop in python with an input () statement somewhere in the code, pull the information in java, print it into a file and then try to read them in python. but because you know java, you are more experienced than me.

Comment: also on python: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Could you please provide a working example of what you have tried with `import wikipedia`? Also, consider rewording "this task can be solved with wikipedia package on the first string".

Comment: @Andreus I am currently testing import wikipedia. I meant "Are there any ways to solve this task except using import wikipedia?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using [Wikipedia-API](https://pypi.org/project/Wikipedia-API/)

**Code**

```
from itertools import groupby
import wikipediaapi

def get_categorymembers(categorymembers):
    '''
        Generator all categories a page belongs too
    '''
    for c in categorymembers.values():
        yield c.title
    
# Get Wikipedia api for english
wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')

# Get Wikipedia page for UN (based upon title)
page_un = wiki_wiki.page("Category:Member states of the United Nations")

# Generator for categories for page
categories = get_categorymembers(page_un.categorymembers)

# Drop first (since its just the starting page which is UN page)
next(categories )

# Sort alphabetically
categories = sorted(categories)

# Group by first letter of name
groups = groupby(categories, lambda k: k[0])

# Show First letter and count for group
for k, v in groups:
    print(k, len(list(v)))
```

**Output**

Note: B only has 16 since Bahamas is called "The Bahamas" so placed in T letter group.

```
A 11
B 16
C 15
D 5
E 9
F 4
G 10
H 3
I 8
J 3
K 6
L 9
M 18
N 10
O 1
P 9
Q 1
R 5
S 26
T 12
U 8
V 3
Y 1
Z 2
```

**Countries Containing letter A**

*Code*

```
from itertools import groupby
import wikipediaapi

def get_categorymembers(categorymembers):
    '''
        Prints all categories a page belongs too
    '''
    for c in categorymembers.values():
        yield c.title
    
def chunk_list(seq, size):
    ' Break list in to chunks '
    return (seq[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(seq), size))

wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')

page_un = wiki_wiki.page("Category:Member states of the United Nations")
# Get Wikipedia pa
countries = get_categorymembers(page_un.categorymembers)
next(countries)  # Drop first since just overalll category

# Countries with a in name
contains_a = [c for c in countries if 'a' in c.lower()]

# Show list (4 per line)
for sublist in chunk_list(contains_a, 4):
    print(*sublist)
```

*Out*

```
Afghanistan Albania Algeria Andorra
Angola Antigua and Barbuda Argentina Armenia
Australia Austria Azerbaijan The Bahamas
Bahrain Bangladesh Barbados Belarus
Bhutan Bolivia Bosnia and Herzegovina Botswana
Brazil Bulgaria Burkina Faso Cambodia
Cameroon Canada Cape Verde Central African Republic
Chad China Colombia Democratic Republic of the Congo
Costa Rica Croatia Cuba Denmark
Dominica Dominican Republic East Timor Ecuador
El Salvador Equatorial Guinea Eritrea Estonia
Eswatini Ethiopia Finland France
User talk:FuzionEXA Gabon The Gambia Georgia (country)
Germany Ghana Grenada Guatemala
Guinea Guinea-Bissau Guyana Haiti
Honduras Hungary Iceland India
Indonesia Iran Iraq Republic of Ireland
Israel Italy Ivory Coast Jamaica
Japan Jordan Kazakhstan Kenya
Kiribati Kuwait Kyrgyzstan Laos
Latvia Lebanon Liberia Libya
Lithuania Madagascar Malawi Malaysia
Maldives Mali Malta Marshall Islands
Mauritania Mauritius Federated States of Micronesia Moldova
Monaco Mongolia Mozambique Myanmar
Namibia Nauru Nepal Kingdom of the Netherlands
New Zealand Nicaragua Nigeria North Korea
North Macedonia Norway Oman Pakistan
Palau Panama Papua New Guinea Paraguay
Poland Portugal Qatar Romania
Russia Rwanda Saint Kitts and Nevis Saint Lucia
Saint Vincent and the Grenadines Samoa San Marino São Tomé and Príncipe
Saudi Arabia Senegal Serbia Sierra Leone
Singapore Slovakia Slovenia Solomon Islands
Somalia South Africa South Korea South Sudan
Spain Sri Lanka Sudan Suriname
Switzerland Syria Tajikistan Tanzania
Thailand Tonga Trinidad and Tobago Tunisia
Turkmenistan Tuvalu Uganda Ukraine
United Arab Emirates United States Uruguay Uzbekistan
Vanuatu Venezuela Vietnam Zambia
Zimbabwe
```

Comment: Okay, it is working. Thank you. The new step is to do the same, but the name of the country should contain at least one "A" letter. In which part of the code should I write this restriction (if "A" in categories:) to display the result, but with this restriction?

Comment: @user280617--recently saw your message. and so updated answer.  Does this answer your question?